# Do you have a better way to use currying for add operation?

Tags: javascript, currying

I want to write an add function that produces the correct output for each of these expressions.

```
add(1)(2, 3)(4)   
add(1)(2)(3)(4)  
add(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I have tried three methods, but all three methods are flawed. Do you have a better method?

Here are the three methods I tried:

1. ```
   function add() {
     var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
     var fn = function() {
       arg = arg.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
       return add.apply(null, arg);
     }
     fn.valueOf = function() {
       return arg.reduce(function(a, b) {
         return a + b;
       })
     }
     return fn;
   }
   console.log(add(1,2,3,4));
   console.log(add(1)(2,3)(4));
   console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4));
   ```

The drawback is that in chrome this method prints an f character (representing a function) before each result, and in Firefox it does not take effect and simply prints as a function.

2. ```
   function curry(fn) {
     var arg = [];
     return function() {
       if(arguments.length === 0) {
         return fn.apply(null, arg);
       }
       else {
         arg = arg.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
         return arguments.callee;
       }
     }
   }
   var add = curry(function() {
     var arg = [].slice.call(arguments);
     return arg.reduce(function(a, b) {
       return a + b;
     })
   })
   console.log(add(1, 2, 3, 4)(10, 20)());  // 40
   ```

The drawback is that each use requires an extra call to tell the function that it's time to call fn, otherwise the result is the function itself.

3. ```
   function curry(fn, length) {
     return function currying(...arg) {
       if(arg.length < length) {
         return function(...arg1) {
           return currying.apply(this, arg.concat(arg1));      
         }
       }
       else {
         return fn.apply(this, arg);
       }
     }
   }
   var add = curry(function(...arg) {
     return arg.reduce(function(a, b) {
       return a + b;
     })
   }, 4)   // This 4 right here means the number of Numbers to add
   ```

The drawback is that you need to know in advance how many Numbers to add and pass it to curry as a parameter.

Comment: *"The drawback is that in chrome this method prints an f character (representing a function) before each result"* Why is the format of the console output a drawback?

Comment: @ziggywiggy because all those functions return a function? I'd rather give up and use cleaner OOP approach `add(1).add(2).print()` or whatever

Comment: `Number(add(1)(2)(3, 4))` works perfectly and returns an actual sum. So you can force converting output to number when you know it is the latest call.

Comment: So, it is actually will work correctly, even without an explicit conversion (`add(1,2) + add(3,4)`), until you `console.log` it, and then you need to explicitly set the type.

Comment: @Chay22: I was asking why console output would make a difference, since in real world code, it shouldn't. But I agree that in practice, I'd rather use the code you show.